Check Airdrop eligablity without connecting my wallet
I´ve seen couple Site which can proof if you are eligable for a solana airdrop or not. Im asking how does that actually work in the background. Do they proof if your wallet fill the airdrop requirements or do they use any specific API. But what make me doubt is, that they also know u can claim.
Would be nice if anyone can explain me that.

Anybody can view the assets held by a wallet, and its transaction history, just by knowing its address. That's generally enough for them to assess it against the airdrop requirements. As an example here's the account that owns the domain toly.sol on an explorer: https://solana.fm/address/86xCnPeV69n6t3DnyGvkKobf9FdN2H9oiVDdaMpo2MMY/transactions

Yeah, but how do they know how much the wallet is allowed to claim? They know the exact amount, do they just set their own guess amount or what?
